# Unable to git clone on Mac while works on Windows using my private keys

Tags: git, macos, private-key

I'm currently migrating my files from windows to mac. One of them is all my git repositories. What I did on Windows is I have my .ppk and public keys generated from PuttyGen then use Pageant to add the .ppk file while cloning from git repo. I use GitExtension in Windows.

Now on Mac, I create a local repo folder where all the cloned repo will be stored. put my public and private keys to ~/.ssh/. and edited ~/.ssh/config and added something like this:

```
     Host 192.168.20.4
        User git
        HostName 192.168.20.4
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user_git.ppk
```

I'm thinking that all was set up but still im getting a:

```
    MACBOOKs-MacBook-Pro:.ssh username$ git clone 
    git@192.168.20.4:repositories/project-repo.git
    Cloning into 'project-repo'...
    Enter passphrase for key '/Users/username/.ssh/user_git.ppk': 
    git@192.168.20.4's password: 
    Permission denied, please try again.
    git@192.168.20.4's password: 
    Permission denied, please try again.
    git@192.168.20.4's password: 
    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Every time I clone from windows with the private key, it doesn't ask password or passphrase.

I have also used GitKraken and used the private_key there but still Permission denied

I already copied the keys from windows to mac multiple time but still doesn't work at all.

What set up was still missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPK is a PuTTY-specific format for private keys. You have to convert it to an OpenSSH format key.

```
$ puttygen user_git.ppk -O private-openssh -o user_git
```

[See this answer for more details](https://superuser.com/a/232365).

Comment: I just followed the tutorial from your link and used the private key in ~/.ssh/config. And now it works! thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Host and Hostname are the same IP. I think the Host should be your project specific IP, and the Hostname should be github's IP, like:

```
# Foo Account
Host github.com-foo
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo.pem
```